# Sending signal to process in background

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I am writing simple http app and to test it I need to do some request via curl, etc. But this makes me switch panes in tmux and I am lazy. Is something like this possible:

I have some script.sh (pseudocode):

```
while(true) { wait for SOME_SIG curl url }
```

And in terminal I run:

./script.sh &

./server

So my current process is `server`. Is there possibility for me to send signal to background process - `script.sh` to issue curl request?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`trap`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).  For example, the following script would execute the function `foo` upon receiving `SIGABRT`:

```
foo() {
  echo "I received SIGABRT; lets do something here"
}

trap foo SIGABRT

while : ; do
  sleep 5s
done
```

(To elaborate, saying `kill -ABRT pid` where `pid` refers to the numeric PID of the above script would trigger `foo`.)